# Adding information in a particular text

Tags: python

I have a text file, and the content is as follows:

```
id  income  gender  
1   6423435 female  
2   1245638 male  
3   6246554 female  
4   9755105 female  
5   5345215 female  
6   5624209 female  
7   8294732 male
```

I want to add two more information to it , gender code(0 or 1) and another income data, and then I want to save it as another text, but this time each line should be like the following:

```
id;income;gender;anotherincome;gender_coded
```

In this case, how can I add the two information in the text?

Comment: Read the existing file, parse it into e.g. a list of tuples or whatever, then iterate over that list while writing to a new file, taking care to use the new format and supply more data. There, now you go and *write some code*. :)

Comment: How is the other income data and gender code data stored, and how are they linked to the data in the text file?

Comment: You should write a line in your text file `file.writelines( list( "%s\n" % item for item in list ) )`